# How to Change CSS style of the same element that is NOT Hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu li{
    width:80px;
}
#menu li:hover {
    width:200px;
}
```

I want to set the width of **OTHER** `<li>s` **THAT ARE NOT HOVERED** to 60PX while one of them are Hovered, and then set width back to 80PX when all of them are not hovered.. how Would I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/s7qVD/

Comment: Are these `<li>`'s generated dinamically? If not, why don't you try using an advances selector such as `:first-child` or `:last-child` or using something like that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tMRb3/2/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny and Unknown you are missunderstanding.

Comment: @BoudiAlSayed that's not simply possible. you need to use jquery...

Comment: @BoudiAlSayed are you willing to do for inner lists? if so, that's easy.... like this http://jsfiddle.net/s7qVD/1/ ?

Comment: Not advanced selectors... I just want to apply 60px width to unhovered li (all li's) and apply 200px to hovered.. and when all of them are unhovered they will set back to 80px ...

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tMRb3/3/

Comment: How do you mean C? He has asked for 60px when all unhovered, starting at 80px, and increase to 200px on the `<li>` that is hovered as Arun has posted.

Comment: @C-link, No that is not what I want.. I have no problem using jquery if i have no choice... but how to alter all NON hovered with a property different then the HOVERED one?

Comment: @DeeKayy90 not sure whether it is what OP wants until he/she confirms it

Comment: @BoudiAlSayed did you had a look at the above fiddles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to set the width of OTHER `<li>s` THAT ARE NOT HOVERED to 60PX while one of them are Hovered, and then set width back to 80PX when all of them are not hovered

With jquery you can do like this:

```
$('#menu li').hover(function(){
    $('#menu li').css('width','60px');
    $(this).css('width','80px');
},function(){
   $('#menu li').css('width','80px');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7qVD/3/)

Comment: C, it's close however it does not set the width of all back to 80px when they are not hovered.

Comment: Worked too thanks... jquery isn't working for me at local test will try to fix this

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#menu li').hover(function () {
        $(this).width(200).siblings().width(60)
    }, function () {
        $(this).siblings().addBack().width(80)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tMRb3/)

Comment: idk why but I'm having a buggy result in chrome and IE.. the li didn't expand to 200px

Comment: This Worked! but it is not working with local site test idk why... im trying to fix it

Answer (score 0):

To select `li` elements that are not `:hover`ed, consider trying:

```
#menu li{
    width:80px;
    color: green;
}
#menu:hover li{
    color: yellow;
}
#menu li:hover {
    width:200px;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) cannot contains another pseudo class. `It matches an element that is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.`

Comment: Yes, as @ArunPJohny pointed out, I made a wrong assumption about the behavior of the negation pseudo selector. I've updated the answer to use the `:hover` filter on an ancestor to apply the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by simply using :hover on both li and ul.

```
    ul li{
       width:80px;
    }

    ul:hover li{
       width: 60px;
    }

    #menu li:hover {
       width:200px;
    }
```